# Using a K-NN Classification Approach for Time Series Data?

Tags: neural-network, clustering, unsupervised-learning

I have a dataset which contains time-series data of water flow over time.  I have a flow meter connected to a kitchen faucet, and I am trying to cluster or classify specific water usage events.

The data is collected every second, and in each row I am given a value for the amount of gallons which are flowing through my flow meter.

For example, I am trying to classify someone washing their hands, filling a teapot, cleaning dishes, etc...

Is this something that I can use a k-NN Classification Approach to cluster these events?  If a clustering based approach isn't good, what other method of classified would be good for this type of data?

If I run some experiments, I can classify each event and turn it into a supervised learning problem.  But at the moment, none of the water events are classified.

A very abridged version of my dataset looks like the following:

[image: Time Series Water Usage]

EDIT

```
water = pd.DataFrame(shower1)
rng = pd.date_range('2016-09-01 00:00:00', '2016-09-30 23:59:58', freq='S')
water = water.reindex(rng,fill_value=0.0)
water = water['shower1']
df = pd.DataFrame({'time_stamp':rng,'water_amount':water})

starts = (df['water_amount']>0)&(df['water_amount'].shift(1)==0) #find all starts of events
n_events = sum(starts) #total number of events
df.loc[starts,'event_number'] = range(1,n_events+1) #numerate starts from 1 to n
df['event_number'] = df['event_number'].fillna(method='pad').fillna(-1) #forward fill all the values
df.loc[df['water_amount']==0,'event_number']=-1 #set all event numbers to -1 where the water amount is 0

df.groupby('event_number').agg({'time_stamp':'first',
                                    'water_amount':'sum'}) #feature matrix
```

[image]

Comment: For finding nearest neighbors, all samples have to be of the same dimension which doesn't seem to be the case here, so I would discard this method. You need something robust to different time series lengths. Training an HMM could be a solution but it usually works best in a supervised framework (with some labeled data for the training phase)...

Comment: When you say that `all samples have to be of the same dimension`, are you saying that since my samples do not represent the same event, that they're of different dimension?  Thanks for your response.  I'll take a look at HMMs.

Comment: No, I'm saying that k-NN search relies on a distance. And that the distance between a sample of dimension K and a sample of dimension M, with K not equal to M, is not naturally defined. In your example, Event 1 is a 5D sample, Event 2 a 2D sample and event 3 a 3D sample. I do not see how you can come up with a k-NN variant that will allow you to compare these different data samples... The best way is to see them as time-series (as you first said), but them k-NN is not a time-series clustering method (or at least not in its classical form).

Comment: As your time series don't all have the same length, you have to be mindful when choosing the clustering method so that it is robust to length difference (which is the case of HMMs and of most probably more methods)

Comment: Do you think the HMM could be used for unsupervised clustering based on the volume or duration of the flow?

Comment: It could, maybe training it on multiple samples and then using the Viterbi algorithm to get the most probable sequence of hidden states and infer from them the most probable event class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems pretty clear from looking at the data *when* an event starts and ends(basically whenever there is a sequence of positive values). So, instead of starting with some complicated models, I'd suggest calculating a few simple features (like length of the event, total amount of water, amount/seconds, time to previous event, time of day in seconds from start of recording) for every event and then try some clustering algorithm on that new data. k-NN might even produce something meaningful. But a statistical summary of the features can probably already give you a better idea of how to further approach this.

EDIT1

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = pd.date_range('2017-01-01 14:00:00', '2017-01-01 14:01:00', freq='S')
water = [0,0,0.2,0.3,0.4,0,0,0.3,0.2,0.5]*6+[0]
df = pd.DataFrame({'time_stamp':rng,'water_amount':water,'event_number':np.zeros(len(water))})

j = 1
for k in range(len(df)):
    if df.ix[k,'water_amount']== 0:
        df.ix[k,'event_number'] = -1
    else:
        if df.ix[k-1,'water_amount'] > 0:
            df.ix[k,'event_number'] = df.loc[k-1,'event_number']
        else:
            df.ix[k,'event_number'] = j
            j = j+1


df.groupby('event_number').agg({'time_stamp':'first',
                                'water_amount':'sum'}) #feature matrix
```

EDIT2

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-01-01 14:00:00', '2017-01-01 14:01:00', freq='S')
water = [0,0,0.2,0.3,0.4,0,0,0.3,0.2,0.5]*6+[0]
df = pd.DataFrame({'time_stamp':rng,'water_amount':water})

starts = (df['water_amount']>0)&(df['water_amount'].shift(1)==0) #find all starts of events
n_events = sum(starts) #total number of events
df.loc[starts,'event_number'] = range(1,n_events+1) #numerate starts from 1 to n
df['event_number'] = df['event_number'].fillna(method='pad').fillna(-1) #forward fill all the values
df.loc[df['water_amount']==0,'event_number']=-1 #set all event numbers to -1 where the water amount is 0

df.groupby('event_number').agg({'time_stamp':'first',
                                    'water_amount':'sum'}) #feature matrix
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  So you're suggesting that after feature extraction, a k-NN may be more telling, as opposed to trying to apply it to my data as it currently sits. What are some common methods that you would use to accomplish this feature extraction?

Comment: what software/language are you working with? you could for example simply loop through the data and extract one event at a time

Comment: I am using Python.

Comment: Is it possible to iterate through the column, and have a new column for duration, a new column for volume, etc... and place each event into it's own row with these attributes?  Effectively turning this into tabulated data?

Comment: you could iterate through the column and tag every entry with an event number. then group by the event number and aggregate by each event.

Comment: @Gary I added some example code.. probably not very clever but maybe gives you an idea.

Comment: Your code is a great example!  I tried to recreate a similar loop with my code, but since it is over 2,000,000 rows, it was taking quite a few hours to run (so I stopped it).

Comment: @Gary maybe the updated code is a bit faster

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Your example worked great, but when I tried it with my data, the table (in my edited original post) is what I received. I think there is a problem with my reindex, and it's making everything 0.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed my problem!  Thanks again for your help!!!

Comment: One last question - how would I log the ending time of the event?

Comment: same idea but shift(-1) or during aggregation with 'last' instead of 'first'

Comment: Does that show both the start and finish, or just the finish?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52143/discussion-between-ow-and-gary).

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget preprocessing your data.

For example, do **feature extraction**n

- total amount of water
- duration
- variance

Comment: Thanks for your response!  Can you elaborate on common methods used to accomplish feature extraction?

Comment: This is very data specific. You'll have to do this yourself.